# Change asp.net text without compiling the whole website

Tags: asp.net

I have a webpage that I would like to change it copyright text.
The problem is I don't want to compile the whole website.
So in the page.aspx we have:

```html
<div id="CopyrightDIV">
      <span id="copyright" runat="server"></span>
</div>
```

The code behind sets the text on pageload.
How can I set the page.aspx so that it will show the text I set on it and not the text that is given by the page.cs?
Thanks

Comment: What you're trying to say? can you explain it well?

Comment: You mean by javascript ?

Comment: say the Pageload sets the text to "all rights reserved", I want it to say "all rights reserved to Ranch" but I can only change the page.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the final HTML will be rendered to the browser, we can always manipulate that, you can change the text in JavaScript like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
         $('#<%=copyright.ClientId%>').text("Ranch");
    });
 </script>
```

Considering you have imported JQuery library.

Comment: In case the user is a novice with JavaScript, you may want to mention that it is jQuery.

Comment: Also since it is asp.net, the user might need `$('#<%=(copyright.ClientId)%>').text('Ranch');` since the client id will probably be changed.

Comment: @TimBJames - Yup have considered dynamic id, and had mentioned about jQuery already.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, how about pasting a script block directly inline into the page? That way you can hook into the page lifecycle and change the span text at the last possible moment?

```
<script language="c#" runat="server">
public void Page_Render(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ((HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.FindControl("copyright")).InnerText = "Your text here";
}
</script>
```

Here's a rundown of the page lifecycle model. So long as the span was originally being set in the page load or init then you should be able to override this at a latter stage.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx